# Error in showing configurable product

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

Am creating magento configurable products as in the below link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

But when am clicking the drop down list (in my figure)

[image]

ie when clicking the dropdown it will only show the **choose an option**

**But am adding colors as red ,blue and size as small,meadium in back end**

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try do this on your system, it should be the same:

```
grep -RTi 'Choose an Option...' ./app/
./app/code/local/Couturelab/Configurable/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php  : 
    'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php  :
    'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml  :
    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
```

The best way of changing the value will be via Javascript, but you can also just play with changing the Values directly and if that works for you then you can extend / move files to your own namespace.